Pandas Dataframe Prints starting at Fourth Row in Excel
I am using iloc to print every third row in a Pandas Dataframe, but now when it prints to Excel, it prints starting in the fourth row (third excluding header). I want it to print starting at the first row as it normally would. I tried dropnan(), and replace('', np.nan), but it looks like that is not the issue. Thank you for your help!
df3 = pd.DataFrame(
            arraym,
            index=["Amperes"]
        ).T
        
if ll == 3: 
       df3 = df3.iloc[::-3, :]



We need to see code that populates the dataframe and reproduces this problem. As it stands - hard to say. Most likely your df does have these "blank" rows so they are part of your output.

When I print the dataframe, I get this-    Amperes
8  0.21031
5  0.21031
2  0.21042

Okay - we still need a reproducible example (with data) and the code that does this excel output step.

What is the output of type(arraym) and list(arraym)?

The following worked. I assume it was writing to Excel starting at the index that made up the "first" row.
df3 = df3.iloc[::-3, :]
df3 = df3.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)

